# Android background tasks, the UI Thread and configuration changes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

In order to tackle the issue of saving background tasks across configuration changes, I've decided instead of retaining a fragment, to do the following:

- in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState)`:

  - cancel any currently running tasks
  - put their id's in the bundle
- in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState)`:

  - restart any tasks, whose id's are in the bundle

Since the tasks I'm dealing with are not particularly long, restarting them isn't an issue, it's not like I'm downloading a big file or something.

Here's what my `TaskManager` looks like:

```
public class BackgroundTaskManager {
    // Executor Service to run the tasks on
    private final ExecutorService              executor;        
    // list of current tasks
    private final Map<String, BackgroundTask>  pendingTasks;
    // handler to execute stuff on the UI thread
    private final Handler                      handler;

    public BackgroundTaskManager(final ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;        
        this.pendingTasks = new HashMap<String, BackgroundTask>();        
        this.handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    private void executeTask(final BackgroundTask task) {
       // execute the background job in the background
       executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.doInBackground();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // manipulate some views
                        task.onPostExecute();
                        // remove the task from the list of current tasks
                        pendingTasks.remove(task.getId());                        
                        // check if the list of current tasks is empty
                    }
                 });
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adds a task to the manager and executes it in the background
     * 
     * @param task
     *            the task to be added
     */
    public void addTask(final BackgroundTask task) {        
        pendingTasks.put(task.getId(), task);
        executeTask(task);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // check if there are pendingTasks
        if (!pendingTasks.isEmpty()) {
            executor.shutdown();            
            savedInstanceState.putStringArray("pending tasks", pendingTasks.keySet().toArray(new String [1]));
        }
    }
}
```

So, `pendingTasks.put()` and `pendingTasks.remove()` is executed only on the UI thread, provided that I call `addTask()` in the UI thread, so I don't need any synchronization.

At this point, I've got some questions:

- Are the activity lifecycle methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` executed on the UI thread?
- Does `executor.shutdown()` return immediately?

The documentation says that `executor.shutdown()` awaits any previously submitted tasks to complete. So, from the point of view of an executor service, a task is completed after its last command is executed, in this case `handler.post()`. So, if I have any pending tasks when I'm in `onSaveInstanceState()`, it is possible that after the executor has shut down, the UI thread will have some posted runnables to execute, right? And since I'm in `onSaveInstanceState()` the activity is probably going to be destroyed, and in `onRestoreInstanceState()` I will have a new activity? So what happens to the runnables, in which I manipulate some old views? Will these runnables be executed immediately after the activity is recreated? Wouldn't it be better if, before I post a runnable to the UI thread, I check if the executor is currently shutting down and do it only if it isn't? In this case can I be absolutely sure that `executor.isShutdown()` will return `true` after I've called `executor.shutDown()` or do I have to wait any tasks to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Are the activity lifecycle methods onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() executed on the UI thread?

  Yes
- The documentation says that executor.shutdown() awaits any previously submitted tasks to complete.

  No. Where did you see that documentation? [ExecutorService.shutdown](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) reads: `This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use awaitTermination to do that`.

  - So what happens to the runnables, in which I manipulate some old views?

  Nothing good. The activity they address is already destroyed. You should raise a flag and either abandon `task.onPostExecute()`, or save it until activity is recreated. Note you cannot save them in `onSaveInstanceState()` - the runnables themselves should take into account, whether the activity is alive.

  - Will these runnables be executed immediately after the activity is recreated?

  No, until you take care of them. Recreating activity should not only restart background tasks, but also runnables with `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made myself clearer. I meant that after `executor.shutdown()` is called, any currently running tasks will be completed, not terminated prematurely. So does `executor.shutdown()` return immediately and can I rely on `executor.isShutdown()` returning `true` afterwards?

Comment: executor.shutdown() return immediately and executor.isShutdown() become true, but to check if all tasks have finished use isTerminated().

Comment: What if, when I enter `onSaveInstanceState()` and before I have the change to shut the executor down, the UI thread has already been posted some runnables. Is it possible to enter `onSaveInstanceState()` with the UI thread having been posted some runnables waiting to be executed, or Android makes sure this doesn't happen?